# Android XML parsing Not getting out put

Tags: android, xml

How to parse xml like this (A XML which is having an inner tag).I am not getting simpleChoice Node when I try to print it it showing always blank can any one help me.

```
<itemBody>
    <p>Look at the text in the picture.</p>
    <p>
        <img src="images/sign.png" alt="NEVER LEAVE LUGGAGE UNATTENDED"/>
    </p>
    <choiceInteraction responseIdentifier="RESPONSE" shuffle="false" maxChoices="1">
        <prompt>What does it say?</prompt>
        <simpleChoice identifier="ChoiceA">You must stay with your luggage at all times.</simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="ChoiceB">Do not let someone else look after your luggage.</simpleChoice>
        <simpleChoice identifier="ChoiceC">Remember your luggage when you leave.</simpleChoice>
    </choiceInteraction>
</itemBody>
```

What I had tried -

```
         NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("itemBody");
         XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

         for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
         {
             Element e = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
             Log.i("TAG","<p>: " + parser.getValue(e, "p"));

             //Log.i("TAG","Count: " + parser.getValue(e, "choiceInteraction"));
             //Log.i("TAG","Count: " + parser.getValue(e, "p")); 
         }

         NodeList nodeChoiceInteractionList = doc.getElementsByTagName("choiceInteraction");
         for (int j = 0; j < nodeChoiceInteractionList.getLength(); j++) 
         {
             Element eChoiceInteractionList = (Element) nodeChoiceInteractionList.item(j);
             Log.i("TAG","<prompt>: " + parser.getValue(eChoiceInteractionList, "prompt"));
         }

         NodeList simpleChoiceList = doc.getElementsByTagName("simpleChoice");
         for (int j = 0; j < simpleChoiceList.getLength(); j++) 
         {
             Element eSimpleChoice = (Element) simpleChoiceList.item(j);
             Log.i("TAG","<simpleChoice>: " + parser.getValue(eSimpleChoice, "simpleChoice"));
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for  like a child of ItemBody, so you need to iterate over the nodeChoiceInteractionList looking for the simpleChoice node, like you do with the prompt node.

Try also to print in your log the times this codes iterates to give you an idea

```
for (int j = 0; j < nodeChoiceInteractionList.getLength(); j++) 
     {
         Element eChoiceInteractionList = (Element) nodeChoiceInteractionList.item(j);
         Log.i("TAG","<prompt>: " + parser.getValue(eChoiceInteractionList, "prompt"));
       >>Log.i("TAG","<simpleChoice>: " + parser.getValue(eSimpleChoice, "simpleChoice"));
       >>Log.d("Iterate Number",j);
     }
```